# Is return an operator or a function?

Tags: c, function, operators, return, sizeof

This is too basic I think, but how do both of these work?

```
return true;   // 1
```

and

```
return (true); // 2
```

Similar: `sizeof`, `exit`

**My guess:**

> If return was a function, `1` would be
>   erroneous.
>
> So, return should be a `unary
>   operator` that can also take in
>   brackets... pretty much like `unary
>   minus`: `-5` and `-(5)`, both are
>   okay.

**Is that what it is - a unary operator?**

Comment: If `return` were a function, how would it return from itself?

Comment: @Nefrubyr: void functions do not need explicit return statements.

Comment: sizeof is a compile-time command. As a corollary
A pretty famous gotchas is that sizeof(f()) doesn't actually call f.

Comment: @Nefrubyr: Great question abut Ha! He got you! Awesome interplay. Love this stuff.

Comment: Any operator can take brackets, and you can use any amount of them, eg. `return(((((5)))));`

Comment: @el.pescado: There is no operator there.  Any expression can have parens added.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`return` is a ***keyword*** that *manipulates control flow*. In that it's similar to `if`, `for` etc. It can be used with or without an expression (`return;` returns from a `void` function). Of course, as with all expressions, extra parentheses are allowed. (So `return (42);` is similar to `int i = (4*10+2);`, in both cases the parentheses are redundant, but allowed.)

`sizeof` is a ***keyword*** that is an *operator*, similar to `new`, `delete`, `+`, `->`,  `::`, etc.

`std::exit()` is an ***identifier*** that denotes a *function* of the C standard library (which never returns to the caller).

Comment: I thought `sizeof()` was a macro? Or at least only calculated at compile time?

Comment: nevermind, `sizeof()` was a compile-time keyword in C89, but now is a runtime thing (due to VLA's, yuck!)

Comment: @xyld: It's still a __keyword__ and it's still an __operator__. `:)`

Comment: `new`, `delete`, `::` are not keywords/operators in C ;-)

Comment: @BlueMoon: Indeed. And this question didn't even _used_ to have a `[C++]` tag. What can I say? I was younger back then, less experienced, alone in the dark, and afraid. I am sorry.

Answer (score 27):

`return` is just a language/control flow construct. It's certainly not a function, since it's syntactically irreducible, and it's not really an operator either, since it has no return value.

Comment: @Will Vousden: what is a "control flow construct", apart from what the name tells me?

Comment: Nice point. If `return` had a `return` value, it would be a little too much recursive ;)

Comment: @eSKay: A control flow construct is something that alters the flow of program control. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow `return` could also be considered a language construct, since it is actually part of the language's syntax. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_construct

Comment: @eSkay: I've grappled with this concept in other languages and totally understand. What helped me most is to understand that sometimes the language has special things and mechanisms that I as the programmer am not allowed to touch, mimic or simulate through the features the language provides to me. A bad analogy might be: the pilot has more access to features of the plane even though you both fly on the same plane and both access common mechanisms made available like seats, food and life jackets.

Comment: .. and the language doesn't have to eat its own dogfood. Oh, I have a lot of these and they're all just as bad. No, actually, they continue to get worse.

Answer (score 17):

`return` is not an operator and is not a function. `return` is a keyword that forms a ***return statement***, which belongs to the category of *jump statements*. In that regard it has absolutely no similarities with either `sizeof` or `exit`.

The requirement to put `()` around the argument of `return` existed in ancient pre-standard versions of C (CRM C, for example), but was quickly eliminated, even though the quirky habit to wrap the argument of `return` in superfluous `()` can be seen from time to time even today.

Comment: @AndreyT: are `sizeof` and `exit` operators?

Comment: @eSKay: `sizeof` is an operator. `exit` is a stanadard library function.

Comment: okay... so in case of an error condition in my program where I need to abort, should I use `exit(0)` or a `return`? Is there some situation where `exit(0)` should be preferred?

Comment: @eSKay: `return` will not abort your program. `return` ends the current function, so `return` will only end the program if done in `main`. In that case (in `main`) you can do either. But I see no need for `exit` in `main`, when a plain `return` will do the job.

Answer (score 7):

return is a control flow keyword, just like `goto`, `break`, `continue`, `if`, `else` ... Do not think of it as an operator, because it does not alter the value behind it. The `()` are just to evaluate expressions and the result of the evaluated expression will be passed along to the calling function (how depends om compiler implementation).

It is also certainly no function, just think about it: how would you return from return?

Answer (score 4):

"return" is neither a routine nor an operator.

It translates to well known assembler instruction.  For example, on the x86 architecture, it translates to "ret", and on the PowerPC, architecture it translates to "blr".

For the value it returns, the compiler moves that value into the appropriate register(s) prior to issuing the return instruction.  On the x86 architecture, this is typically EAX and EDX if necessary--the registers will change slightly for x86-64.  On PPC, if memory serves, it is r1--others may correct me if I am wrong on that detail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I remember, r1 is the stack pointer and r3 the return value.  See figure A-1 here: http://wall.riscom.net/books/proc/ppc/cwg/a_abi.html

Answer (score 2):

```
'true' is an Expression, 
'(true)' is an Expression.
```

return can always be followed by an expression, but for the return to type check, the expression must have the same type of the return type of the function.

hense you can generalize it by saying

```
return Expression.
```

(In a function with a `void` return type, `return` may not be followed by an expression; a bare `return` simply exits the function.)

Answer (score 0):

"The requirement to put () around the argument of return  existed in ancient pre-standard versions of C (CRM C, for example), but was quickly eliminated, even though the quirky habit to wrap the argument of return in superfluous () can be seen from time to time even today."

Yeah, you know you are looking at some old code or someone thinks return is a function when you see them using parens with it all the time.
My college instructor did that and it annoyed me all the time.
Oh well at least he was consistent.