# Whats the order of operations with respect to 'return' in C

Tags: c, return-value, operator-precedence, post-increment

I was shocked by the output of this... been coding in C for a few years now.
Could someone explain a possible use case? Seems like it should be a compiler warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int chk(int var)
{
    return var++;
}

int main (void)
{
    int a = 1;

    a = chk(a);

    printf("var is: %d\n", a);

    return 0;

}
```

`var is: 1`

Comment: What value did you expect? Maybe pre-increment is the operator you wanted to use?

Comment: Why are you "shocked" and why do you think the compiler should issue a warning?

Comment: I find this to be completely expected. On the other hand, if `++var` returned 1, I would be shocked.

Comment: Well, since return isn't on the order of operations, I assumed it was the very last thing to be executed

Comment: @G.M.: warnings "this operation has no effect" are absolutely welcome.

Comment: A `return` statement with an expression evaluates the expression to determine the function's return value, then terminates the function.  If `var` initially has value `1`, then the result of evaluating `var++` is `1`.  That evaluating that expression also produces a side effect on the value of `var` is irrelevant.

Comment: _Could someone explain a possible use case?_ Not in this case, but it can be useful switching to `static`:  `int chk(void){static int var = 1; return var++;}` returns the number of times the function has been called :)

Comment: @David Ranieri;some hardware land voodoo

Comment: *Could someone explain a possible use case?* -- why does it need a use case?  The observed behavior is a direct, natural consequence of the semantics of the language.  There is no special rule involved to specify that result.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, first time I have ever heard of an operator being referred to as a side effect, lol

Comment: *Seems like it should be a compiler warning* -- I could see a compiler warning about that, but that's between you and your compiler.  C compilers are not responsible for warning about every detail of your code that they suspect might constitute a mistake.

Comment: @Greasyjoe, I didn't say that an operator *was* a side effect, I said it *has* ("produces") a side effect.  Evaluating an expression produces a value.  Evaluating some expressions also produces changes in the program state, which the C language specification describes as "side effects".  The change in the stored value of the operand of `++` is such an effect.  So, by the way, is the change in the value of the left-hand operand of an `=` operator.

Comment: @Greasyjoe It is executed last. And the answer is still 1. Hint: what number is `var++`?

Comment: @Greasyjoe "some hardware land voodoo" - Perhaps `var` probably isn't local to `chk` and has lifetime beyond the function (your contrived example probably isn't equivalent). If that's the case it may make sense to "return the current value and then increment it". Maybe you can post the *actual* code where you saw this part.

Comment: Also, `return` is not an operator. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781278/.

Comment: This was basically, it. It was a state machine returning an index which was incremented each time it was called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Perhaps a better way to say this might be that my grievance is that the definition of 'return' just says it returns the result of the experession.
Is x++ not an expression?!?

Somewhere I am missing the difference between { x++; return x} and { return x++; }

Comment: @Greasyjoe, absolutely `x++` is an expression.  And it evaluates to the *initial* value of `x`, prior to the increment.  That's the difference between `x++` and `++x` (both have the same side effect on the value of `x`, but the latter *evaluates to* 1 + the initial value of `x`).  The behavior you describe reflects exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
> operand.** As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
> incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
> it).

So the return statement in the function

```
int chk(int var)
{
    return var++;
}
```

returns the value of the parameter `var` before incrementing it. So acrually the postfix incrementing in this return statement does not have an effect and is equivalent to

```
return var;
```

That is the function returns the original value of the argument expression.

The function would be more meaningful if for example instead of the postfix increment operator it used the unary increment operator like

```
int chk(int var)
{
    return ++var;
}
```

In this case the function returns incremented value of the the value of the argument expression.

Answer (score 0):

In the computing model the C standard uses, `return var++;` has a main effect of return the value of `var` and a side effect of incrementing `var`. The value of `var` used for the `return` is the value prior to the increment.

Because `var` is a parameter of the function, incrementing it affects only the value of the parameter. It does not affect the argument `a` in the calling routine.

> Seems like it should be a compiler warning.

Yes, this code performs a side effect that has no use, which could suggest a mistake by the author, so it is reasonable a compiler would warn about it.